# Why the inner array elements are not getting sorted in descending order of time stamp value in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array, key-value

I've an associative array titled `$things` as follows :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [feed_id] => 4930
            [app_id] => 0
            [privacy] => 0
            [privacy_comment] => 0
            [type_id] => poll

            [likes] => Array
                (
                )

            [marks] => Array
                (
                )

            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => 
                        )

                )

            [server_time] => 1438157330
            [user_group_name] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [feed_id] => 4914
            [app_id] => 0
            [privacy] => 0
            [privacy_comment] => 0
            [type_id] => poll
            [likes] => Array
                (
                )

            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [is_liked] => 
                            [comment_id] => 1660
                            [parent_id] => 0
                            [type_id] => poll
                            [item_id] => 141
                            [user_id] => 901
                            [owner_user_id] => 901
                            [time_stamp] => 1438083459
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [is_liked] => 
                            [comment_id] => 1661
                            [parent_id] => 0
                            [type_id] => poll
                            [item_id] => 141
                            [user_id] => 901
                            [owner_user_id] => 901
                            [time_stamp] => 1438083467
                         )

                )

            )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [feed_id] => 4926
            [app_id] => 0
            [privacy] => 0
            [privacy_comment] => 0
            [type_id] => poll
            [likes] => Array
                (
                )

            [marks] => Array
                (
                )

            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => 
                        )

                )

            )

    [comments] => 
)
```

I want to sort the inner array `['comments']` in descending order of time stamp values without preserving the keys, so I wrote following code for it.

```
usort($things['comments'],function($a,$b) {
  return $b['time_stamp'] - $a['time_stamp'];
});
print_r($things); die;
```

I'm not understanding why it's not getting sorted in descending order of time stamp values?

Please somebody help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `foreach($things as &$th) { usort($th['comments'],function($a,$b) {
  return $b['time_stamp'] - $a['time_stamp'];
}); }`

Comment: $things['comment'] doesn't exist.... $things[0]['comment'] exist so loop trough your element

Comment: @splash58 : Thank you so much for your help. Just a small request from me. Post this as your answer so that I can accept it and forward my sincere gratitude for you. Thanks once again for your immense help.

Comment: @user2839497 i did it. Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of the structure of the array column `comments` may be acheived not as `$things['comments']' but`$things[$i]['comments']. Or easier use foreach loop, for example so

```
foreach($things as &$th) 
    usort($th['comments'], 
           function($a,$b) { return $b['time_stamp'] - $a['time_stamp']; });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to first check within your array that it contains `time_stamp` key or not and then need to use `usort` as

```
foreach($things as &$th) {
    if(array_key_exists('time_stamp',$th['comments'])){
        usort($th['comments'], 
               function($a,$b) { return $b['time_stamp'] - $a['time_stamp']; }); 
    }
}
```